# Sometimes databse is created but sometimes it isn't

Tags: sql, windows, powershell, sqlite

I just started with sql using sqlite 3.7.17. I tried reading through [here](http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex0.html). As suggested I ran

```
create table test (id);
.quit
```

commands in sqlite terminal. No .db file was created in the current directory.

Then I tried to read through [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html) and ran

```
sqlite3 test.db
```

in the terminal. No .db file was created but sqlite terminal opened up. I ran

```
;
.quit
```

in the sqlite terminal and the .db file was created.

I am using Windows 7 and the terminal that I keep talking about is the Windows Powershell. I have placed the binaries for Windows in `C:\Windows\system32\` folder so that the terminal recognizes sqlite3.

What did I do wrong? Why was .db file created once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you probably ran `sqlite3` without specifying a database file, so the program wouldn't know which file to create. In the second case you specified a file, but it isn't created before you're running an actual SQL statement against it (`;` is an empty SQL statement, but a statement nonetheless).